# Calculating area of pixles for certain Aspect value per specific area?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, aspect

I am using ArcGIS 10.6. I have the aspect (raster file) for the roof of buildings at the city scale. Now I want to calculate the area of each aspect group per building. I tied zonal statistics, zonal geometry and etc . Also reclassified the aspect layer and tried to add the Building ID but I didn't get the desired result.

How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by **polygonizing** the aspect raster, and then calculate **$Area** into a new field via **field calculator**. This is the whole workflow.